# insert a node at end and delete a node at beginning in double linked list

Tags: c, linux, malloc, doubly-linked-list

Double linked list program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node  
{
    int data;
    struct node *rnext;
    struct node*lnext;
}*first=NULL,*last=NULL;

void  display()
{
    struct node*temp;

    if(first==NULL)
    {
        printf("list is empty\n");
        return;
    }

    temp=first;

    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d \n",temp->data);
        temp=temp->rnext;
    }
}

void  insertion()
{
    struct node *temp;
    struct node *nn= (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("enter data to be inserted\n");
    nn->rnext=NULL;
    last->rnext=nn;
    nn->lnext=last;
    last=nn;
}

void deletion()
{
    struct node *temp;

    if(first==NULL||last==NULL)
    {
        printf("list is empty\n");
        return;
    }

    temp=first;
    first=first->rnext;
    first->lnext=NULL;
    free(temp);
}

/* main loop */

int  main()    
{
    int option;
    do
    {
        printf("enter option 1.insertion\n2.display\n3.deletion\n4.exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&option);
        switch(option)
        {
            case 1:
                insertion();
                break;
            case 2:
                display();
                break;
            case 3:
                deletion();
                break;
        }
    } while(option!=4);
}
```

i have wrote a double linked list to insert a node at end and delete a node at             beginning in linux using C language.
    but while executing the program getting the error segmentation fault.
    i am also posting the output.

```
./out
enter option 1.insertion
2.display
3.deletion
4.exit
1
enter data to be inserted
12 
Segmentation fault
please help me with the solution for segmentation fault
```

this is my code please help me run it and debug it .I am inserting the node at the end and deleting the node at the end

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: `insertion()` seems fine except you're not checking if `last == NULL`. That would cause a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

During the first insertion, the global variable `last` is equal to 0, so you received a segfault signal.